# Taking away all of persons roles and giving them back after some time

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot that once given a command will take away a persons roles and give them back after a certain amount of time. right now im getting the eror unexpected indent.

here is the code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import ctx
import re
import time
from time import sleep
from discord.ext import rolelist, roles, role

class MyClient(discord.Client):

    async def on_ready(self):
       print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        messageContent = message.content
        if len(messageContent) > 0:
            if re.search("^send.*court$", messageContent):
                user_id = message.mentions[0].id
                user = message.mentions[0]
                await message.channel.send(
                    f"sending <@{user_id}> to court!"
                )
                async def listroles(ctx):
                    user_roles = [role.mention for role in ctx.message.author.roles if role.mentionable]
                    await message.channel.send(user_roles)

                async def roles(ctx):
                    print(", ".join([str(r.id) for r in ctx.guild.roles]))

                role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="Jail")
                await user.add_roles(role)

                    async def roles(user.roles):
                        rolelist = [r.mention for r in user.roles if r != ctx.guild.default_role]
                        roles = ", ".join(rolelist)

                        print(rolelist)


client = MyClient()
client.run('TOKEN_GOES_HERE')
```

Comment: You didn't provide the error message.

Comment: The error was "unexpected indent"

Answer (score 1):

Python don't use `{}` like C# or Java, it works with indentation. So your code should be this:

```
            await user.add_roles(role)

            async def get_roles(user):
                rolelist = [r.mention for r in user.roles if r != ctx.guild.default_role]
                roles = ", ".join(rolelist)

                print(rolelist)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why but it says there is an invalid syntax error in the "user.roles".